# Counting the frequency of an elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Hello I am currently stuck on a homework problem as I have no idea how exactly to approach the problem.

Write a program that reads in a list of integers into an array with base type
int. Provide the facility to either read this array from the keyboard or
from a file, at the user’s option. If the user chooses file input, the program
should request a file name. You may assume that there are fewer than 50
entries in the array. Your program determines how many entries there are.
The output is to be a two-column list. The first column is a list of the distinct
array elements; the second column is the count of the number of
occurrences of each element. The list should be sorted on entries in the
first column, largest to smallest.

So I were to enter: 1, 2, 1, 10, 15, 12, 2, 10, 10
The program should output something like:

List Frequency

1-----2

2-----2

10----3

15----1

I am able to sort the numbers but don't know how I would go about comparing the numbers in the array.

```
#include <iostream>//Input/Output Library
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;//Namespace of the System Libraries

//Global Constants
const int MAX = 10;

//Function Prototypes
void input(int array[], int size);
void sort(int array[],int size);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //Declare Variable
    int array[MAX];
    int size = MAX;

    //Input Data
    input(array, size);
    sort(array, size);

    cout<<"\nSort   Frequency\n";
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void input(int a[], int size){
    cout<<"Enter "<<size<<" numbers for the array: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
}
void sort(int a[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(a[i]>a[j]){
                a[i]=a[i]^a[j];
                a[j]=a[i]^a[j];
                a[i]=a[i]^a[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use a `std::map<int,unsigned>`, not an array. For each input, bump the count for the corresponding map entry. When finished with input, enumerate the map with a `crbegin` to `crend` iterator and dump the results. It's literally about 14 lines of code, including the `#include` list, and whitespace for readibility. And fyi, *no one* uses xor-swapping in the real world for such a trivial task.

Comment: Do you know the possible range of the numbers?  Because if it is (for example) numbers between 0 and 1000 there is an easy answer: just use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort and replace putting the numbers back with printing them out.  But if it can be any number that is possible to store then it is harder: you need to use a map - but a map isn't actually an array so it might not be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @stryku's answer since you only want to print frequencies, you don't even need to create the `v` vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

int main() {

    std::map<int, size_t> counts;

    std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), [&counts](int k) {
        ++counts[k];
    });

    for(const auto &pair : counts)
        std::cout<<pair.first <<" "<< pair.second<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::map<int, size_t> counts;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(v));

    for(const auto &number : v)
        ++counts[number];

    for(const auto &pair : counts)
        std::cout<<pair.first <<" "<< pair.second<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I think your teacher will be surprised if you would explain it to him

Comment: One could also use `std::count`/`std::count_if` to get the counts - might be a bit more clear. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: If you want to be cute, you can actually save yourself the `std::copy` and use ranged constructor of `std::vector`.

Comment: I am trying to implement this into my code but I am getting some warning: range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
main.cpp:53:25: error: request for member 'first' in 'pair', which is of non-class type 'const int'
         std::cout<<pair.first <<" "<< pair.second<<"\n";
                         ^
main.cpp:53:44: error: request for member 'second' in 'pair', which is of non-class type 'const int'
         std::cout<<pair.first <<" "<< pair.second<<"\n"